# How to test decoupled IO of bundle in chisel testers

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel

I'm trying to implement a queue of bundles using chisel

```
class element extends Bundle{
 val data=UInt(32.W)
}
class testQueue extends Module
{
 val io = IO(new Bundle {
   val in = Flipped(Decoupled(new element))
   val out = Decoupled(new element)
 })
 val queue = Queue(io.in, 16) 
 io.out <> queue
}
```

when i use the test api on chisel bootcamp
and the test code is:

```
test(new testQueue()){ c =>
    // Example testsequence showing the use and behavior of Queue
    c.io.in.initSource()
    c.io.in.setSourceClock(c.clock)
    c.io.out.initSink()
    c.io.out.setSinkClock(c.clock)
    
    val testVector = Seq.tabulate(100){ i => {
      val s=Wire(new element())
      s.data :=1.U
      s
    }
}
    c.io.in.enqueueSeq(testVector)
    c.io.out.expectDequeueSeq(testVector)
}
```

the error is :

```
chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Error: Not in a UserModule. Likely cause: Missed Module() wrap, bare chisel API call, or attempting to construct hardware inside a BlackBox.
  chisel3.internal.throwException$.apply(Error.scala:156)
  chisel3.internal.Builder$.forcedUserModule(Builder.scala:494)
  chisel3.WireFactory.apply(Data.scala:636)
  chisel3.WireFactory.apply$(Data.scala:629)
  chisel3.Wire$.apply(Data.scala:667)
```

when I remove "wire" from the last code block
it says

```
chisel3.package$ExpectedHardwareException: data to be connected 'UInt<32>' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type. Perhaps you forgot to wrap it in Wire(_) or IO(_)?
  chisel3.internal.requireIsHardware$.apply(Binding.scala:20)
  chisel3.Data.connect(Data.scala:406)
  chisel3.Data.$anonfun$$colon$eq$1(Data.scala:541)
  scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  chisel3.internal.prefix$.apply(prefix.scala:32)
```

so what should i write to test this testqueue module using the api enqueueSeq and expectDequeueSeq

Answer (score 1):

Chisel in general does not allow construction of hardware elements outside of a `Builder` context. Exceptions to this are basic value types like `UInt`, `SInt`, `Bool` etc. A while ago chisel was changed to allow the creation of `Bundle` literals and `Vec` literals outside of a builder context. This makes unit test coding a bit easier.
Another problem here is you need to use fork with the enqueueSeq, dequeueSeq family.
Try changing the body of your test to something like

```
class QueueBundleTest extends AnyFreeSpec with ChiselScalatestTester {
  "test name" in {
    test(new TestQueue()) { c =>
      // Example test sequence showing the use and behavior of Queue
      c.io.in.initSource()
      c.io.in.setSourceClock(c.clock)
      c.io.out.initSink()
      c.io.out.setSinkClock(c.clock)

      val testVector = Seq.tabulate(100) { i =>
        (new DataElement).Lit(_.data -> 1.U)
      }
      fork {
        c.io.in.enqueueSeq(testVector)
      }.fork {
        c.io.out.expectDequeueSeq(testVector)
      }.join
    }
  }
}
```

I hope that helps.
P.S. you probably intended to make your test a little more robust by changing the test vector to create entries to use `(new DataElement).Lit(_.data -> i.U)`